# using DNS lookup in chroot postfix

Tags: dns, postfix, chroot

I'm trying to set up a postfix set up on my client machines. All machines should use a central ldap directory for common postfix (e.g. aliases, etc). But since postfix runs in chroot postfix is unable to resolve the hostname of the ldap server.

Postfix mail.log lines:

```
Apr 30 13:37:22 host postfix/cleanup[30160]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_connect_to_host: TCP ldapmaster.domain.com:389
Apr 30 13:37:22 host postfix/cleanup[30160]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_connect_to_host: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
Apr 30 13:37:22 host postfix/cleanup[30160]: dict_ldap_debug: ldap_err2string
Apr 30 13:37:22 host postfix/cleanup[30160]: warning: dict_ldap_lookup: Search error -1: Can't contact LDAP server 
Apr 30 13:37:22 host postfix/cleanup[30160]: warning: AF28B226A2: sender_canonical_maps map lookup problem for root@domain.com
```

When I do the ldapsearch manually it works fine. I also tried to enter the chroot environment of postfix (`/var/spool/postfix`) and when I try to `ping ldapmaster.domain.com` I get an `unknown host`-error.

The issue has been [reported to Ubuntu Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postfix/+bug/764096) as [DNS hostname lookups fail in chroot after natty upgrade](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postfix/+bug/764096).

Any ideas how to allow postfix to resolve the DNS names?

Comment: Does the chroot environment include a copy of your /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: Yes. This is done by the init script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that libnss libraries seem are loaded after chroot. So they are needed in the chroot jail. Link them there:

```
cp -vl /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_* /var/spool/postfix/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand why postfix shouldn't be able to resolve DNS names, but just add the DNS of your LDAP-provider to the `/etc/hosts`. So you are independet of any DNS lookups and don't get stuck if the DNS server should fail:

```
1.2.3.4     thehostname
```

Comment: that's one way to solve this. Thanks so far. But i would like to know why postfix is unable to revolve the name via DNS.

Comment: How you got to know that it's a DNS issue? You might post some logs?

Comment: Since DNS queries are resolved via ports `53/tcp` and `53/udp` a Wireshark capture of an attempt should help you. You should be able to see what DNS queries Postfix sends to whom, what the response is, and tons and tons of other packets.