# Postfix problem when started from SSD

Tags: dns, postfix

Ubuntu GNOME 17.04

It seems that I've got a Postfix problem. **I think that it's related to the fact that it's starting from an SSD**, and some required service hasn't fully started yet, causing Postfix to fail at boot time. However, if I just restart Postfix, the required service is there now, and it all works fine.

Here's the trail...

**Here's an example of the error...**

```
~$ mail -s testing root
Cc: 
testing

~$ mailq
-Queue ID-  --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
5703312A0BE4      392 Mon Jun 26 14:10:18  my_username@Satellite-E55.local
(Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=smtp.gmail.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
```

**Looks like a DNS error, huh?**

**So if I look at this...**

```
~$ cd /var/spool/postfix/etc

~$ ls -al
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun 26 14:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root  4096 Apr 14 13:29 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    92 Jun 26 14:08 host.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1955 Jun 26 14:08 hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2845 Jun 26 14:08 localtime
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   544 Jun 26 14:08 nsswitch.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   282 Jun 26 14:08 resolv.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 19183 Jun 26 14:08 services
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 May 12  2014 ssl

~$ more resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

~$
```

**resolv.conf is not properly populated!**

**If I restart Postfix, then resolv.conf is properly populated, and Postfix works fine!**

My thinking is that maybe systemd-resolved hasn't finished starting up when Postfix wants to copy some files into `/var/spool/postfix/etc`, specifically the resolv.conf information, and that's what's causing Postfix to fail.

**If I then...**

```
~$ cd /etc/systemd/system/postfix.service.d

~$ more override.conf 
[Unit]
After=network-online.target
After=systemd-resolved.service

~$
```

**I suspect that this is where the fix must happen? Adding/removing an "After=" definition?**

Any ideas on how to get my Postfix to properly start at boot time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was on the right path to solving my Postfix problem.

**I ended up changing this:**

```
~$ cd /etc/systemd/system/postfix.service.d

~$ more override.conf 
[Unit]
After=network-online.target
After=systemd-resolved.service
```

**To this:**

```
~$ cd /etc/systemd/system/postfix.service.d

~$ more override.conf 
[Unit]
#After=network-online.target
#After=systemd-resolved.service
```

Comment: This simply makes no sense. After tells that postfix should be started only after resolve completely. Now, you remove this dependency. There must be a different reason why it is now working for you.

Comment: See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postfix/+bug/1627117

Comment: @Sebi I read the bug report. It is similar to my problem, but there's no fix for it there. Notice the filename... override.conf. I posted my answer there. Lets follow the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base from terminal with :

```
sudo gedit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

In this, insert :

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Save.

Reboot. You're done.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, my `/etc/resolv.conf` is getting properly populated at boot time, so my problem is not with systemd-resolved. I believe that it's a timing problem due to my SSD.

Comment: Well, I got confused ... one quicky & dirty solution would be to restart postfix at the end at putting /etc/init.d/postfix restart in /etc/rc.local

But really this is a shame ... I would look at the startup logs, and postfix logs to see if any complain there, and find what process needs to be started before postfix, then I would modify the startup script accordingly ...

Comment: However, as I have never seen that ...  and if this is the issue, it will deserve to fill a bug report.

Comment: Also have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/38106/using-dns-lookup-in-chroot-postfix?rq=1